# How can I get the max value of multiple columns (and value of stringcolumn where datecolumn is max) and combine it into a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I do this in SQL?

This is my sample data:

```
ColA   ColB   ColC   ColD   ColE
----   ----   ----   ----   ----
TR12   25     67    yey
TR11   28     99    apr     2/2/2013
TR12   78     55    apr     2/2/2013
TR12   20     35    olf     2/5/2013
```

The condition is to get the max value in ColB and ColC of a certain value in ColA.

For ColD and ColE values, I would like to get them from the line where it has a maximum ColE value.

```
 ColA   ColB   ColC   ColD   ColE
 ----   ----   ----   ----   ----
*TR12*  25     *67*  yey
 TR11   28     99    apr     2/2/2013
 TR12   *78*   55    apr     2/2/2013
 TR12   20     35    *olf*   *2/5/2013*
```

Hence, my expected result would be like this:

```
ColA   ColB   ColC   ColD   ColE
----   ----   ----   ----   ----
TR12   78     67     olf    2/5/2013
```

This is all I have as of now where it could return the correct max value of a column, but what about *returning a string based on the line where ColE is max value*? I am getting an incorrect value when I do max() function for ColD.  I am getting the other word instead of the word where ColE is max.

```
SELECT 
   ColA, max(ColB) as ColB, max(ColC) as ColC,
   max(ColD) as ColD, -- this is where I got it wrong,
      this should return the string where its ColE is the maximum
   max(ColE) as ColE
FROM 
   dbo.SomeTable 
WHERE 
   ColA = 'TR12'
```

I really hope you could help me with this one..

thanks for the quick replies..

Comment: You are doing fine; just keep going and call back with specifi problems.

Comment: im not really sure how to do the ones for ColD and ColE.. thanks

Comment: The max() aggregate function works on strings as well as numerics.

Comment: oh i see.. i get it i get it.. let me get back if there are new problems

Comment: ok i got it! you could have added your comment to the answer so I could tag it as the answer.. =)

Comment: You can answer your own question, just paste your working query and accept it.

Comment: ok!.. will do.. thanks ! especially to @PieterGeerkens

Comment: the max seemed to be not enough.. im not getting my expected results when I use the max for a string.. i am expecting to get the string based on the max value from another column (for example, a date [ColE]).. thanks everyone for quick response

Answer (score 1):

You are doing fine; just keep going. The max() aggregate function works on strings as well as numerics.

Comment: hello again Pieter.. im sorry if this was late.. but i can see that the above does not get the string based on the max value of ColE (date).. the above returns the string 'yey' instead of 'olf' for ColD which is/should be based/aligned with the max value of ColE

Comment: Try checking for leading blanks perhaps.